# how can i add image in html by StringBuilder

Tags: html, web, stringbuilder

```
sbuilder.Append("&size=20&mode=Exact&filter=127\">" + "<img src=\"" + 
        Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, 
        "Images\\free_icons\\Web-Application-Icons-Set\\PNG-16\\Link.png") + 
        "\"  width=18px height=18px /></a><br/>");
```

It works on local but when I published project on web server the image did't show.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\\` in the image path with `/`.

Also, `width` and `height` properties accept numeric values without `px`.